# Ask How To Seting httaccses meta desc title same with oldies web

Tags: meta-tags, meta-description, meta-robots, meta-refresh

How do I setup .htaccses to get meta desc and title same with old web but redirect into new website example.

aaaaaaa.blogspot.com = the old web - We want to get the meta desc and title from original page after that redirect to new web page.

Comment: yes possible we have the example :D

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! ***We want to get the meta desc and title from original page after that redirect to new web page.*** This is not possible as it is. You would have to set up your redirects then edit your new pages to reflect the meta desc and title tags you want.

Comment: Please post your example so that we can better know what you mean. I edited your question to try and make it clearer. Otherwise it would have been closed for being unclear. I just want to get this right for you. Cheers!!

Comment: https://fidicwhitebookfreedownloadpdf.blogspot*com/2020/01/corporate-financial-advisers.html the meta it`s same with the post after one second redirect into new website

Comment: Okay. They are using some sort of redirect after visiting the page. It is likely they are using JavaScript for this. What is your goal? Are you trying to effect search results? If so, I am not sure this will work. I will leave it to others to answer. Cheers!!

Comment: yes I already understand the javascript code. I have tried everything and it works but when I tried to submit it to Google webmaster Google read the description of the new website

Comment: That is right. Search engines will follow the redirect just like a browser would do and ignore the content of the redirecting page and use the content of the target page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect using .htaccess and also affect the title and meta description of the resulting page. .htaccess can rewrite URLs and take you to different places, but it can't change tags on the destination page.

The example you provided is likely using a meta refresh or some other type of redirect, so visitors see the old page briefly, and are then taken to the new one. This type of redirect is often seen by search engines as spammy.

So, if your goal is to get visitors (both human and robot) to the new pages when they use old links, and/or to keep some of the SEO value of the old pages, just use 301 redirects in .htaccess.

Or if your goal is to help visitors (human and robot) to recognize that the old pages are no longer maintained and you have new related content, it may work better if you send visitors to the old pages to a landing page that explains this fact and links out to the new content. (But you'll likely lose some SEO value here because you're funneling visitors from many pages down to one landing page and then back out to many pages. 1-to-1 redirects are the best case scenario for preserving link value.)

Comment: ok thank you for your help elaine